# How to line up/indent this text evenly?

Tags: html

[Pic of Uneven text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMGg8.png)

```html
   <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/iOS7/PNG/25/Business/pricing_structure-25.png" title="Pricing Structure" width="25" style="margin-right: 8px">
Choose ones of our packages or build your own. Choose ones of our packages or build your own. <a href="pricing.html">View pricing.</a>
```

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: What do you want to indent?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content inside of a div element and apply the css code that I listed in the .hang style below.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="hang">
     <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/iOS7/PNG/25/Business/pricing_structure-25.png" title="Pricing Structure" width="25" style="margin-right: 8px">
    Choose ones of our packages or build your own. Choose ones of our packages or build your own. 

    <a href="pricing.html">View pricing.</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hang {
    text-indent: -2.3em;
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

**Working Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/nickcpainter/7vuh2f6k/

Comment: Why the downvote?  Good luck getting answers if you are just going to downvote with no feedback...

Comment: Downvote? I didn't downvote anything. I just opened this up and saw your comment. Anyways, in your jsfiddle, the first line isn't lined up with the rest. I think I might need to put the image in one col and the text in another?

Comment: @RichardMartinez Check the dupe mate.

Comment: @RichardMartinez - Ah must have been someone  else then.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar- So as the one answering the question I can be downvoted because the asker decided not to check for dups?

Comment: @Nick Shall I downvote you and prove that it was not me?

Comment: @Nick Take the downvote man.. `:)` Hope now you are sure that it wasn't me who downvoted you... `:)`

Comment: @Nick And you don't even know that downvoting requires 125 reputation and you were arguing with the OP. Learn to use the site without hurting the feelings of other people who are trying to help you mate!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar  I never accused you of downvoting me.  You responded to this comment so I thought I would ask if there was any problem with answering a question which later turned out to be a duplicate.  I am sorry if you feel that I was accusing you of anything.

Comment: @Nick Just told you mate. I have removed the downvote. You could have been clearer. This answer is definitely a low quality one mate. That's the reason you have got a downvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128656/discussion-between-nick-and-praveen-kumar).